# predefined input in a nohup shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts, input, nohup

I am trying to write a shell script that I can then `nohup` as it is supposed to run for hours. I am a shell novice so I'm struggling with this a lot.

The script should first open some software (ACE data mining suite), which usually prompts the user for some input (choosing one of many possible input files; this can potentially be avoided by only placing one input file in the directory from which the script is called). I then need to start the algorithm by typing its name in (warmr). So in summary I need the script to:

1. open ACE
2. input file name into ACE (optional, can be avoided)
3. start the algorithm by inputting its name

input in steps 2-3 should be predefined -- I do not want to be prompted for it as I know what I want to run.

so far I have `ace_script`:

```
#!/bin/sh

/home/nfg/ACE-ilProlog-1.2.20/linux/bin/ace
```

adding `echo "warmr"` or `read "warmr"` avails to nothing. running `ace_script` fires up ACE which then complains of an error reading from stream and shuts down.

any help or suggestions regarding steps 2-3 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So for avoiding step 2, it's kind of self explained - just have a single file in that directory with what you want to search. As for step 3, you could try using `here string` or xargs, basically the following:`/home/nfg/ACE-ilProlog-1.2.20/linux/bin/ace <<< "warmr"`,or `echo "warmr"  |  xargs /home/nfg/ACE-ilProlog-1.2.20/linux/bin/ace`.  I'd suggest you re-read documentation on that software, perhaps it has an option for  what you are trying to do

Comment: "`ace_script` fires up ACE which then complains of an error reading from stream and shuts down", can you post the command and the error? Also a link to an online `man` page would help a lot. I tried looking at the documentation and apparently you're right, there's no hint on how to run the program non-interactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the contents of a file you use cat:

```
$ cat myfile.txt

cats are cool
I like trains
```

So just cat a file with the algorithm name in it?

---

I'd be surprised if the software didn't already have some sort of way of giving this data to it? Check the documentation - [this PDF](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/ACE/doc/ACEuser-1.2.16.pdf) may be what you need.

Comment: i've read the manual thoroughly and prior to posting here and it does not answer my question. thank you for your answer -- i will try your suggestion